# Cannot update the table by hibernate with different user

Tags: hibernate

I am going to deploy a war to tomcat.
hibernate config:

```
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.1:db11g</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">ime</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">ime</property> 
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>......<mapping class="com.abc.system.menu" />
```

I found that `menu` table could not be created in ime account.
After checking the log, I discovered that same table is created in different user in same database. Like below.

```
2015-04-30 18:18:33,619 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] - <table found: IME3.menu>
 2015-04-30 18:18:33,619 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] - <columns: [id, menuid, stepstatus, step]>
```

Is it a bug of hibernate3?

Comment: I don't think so, creation of table is depending on property `hbm2ddl.auto`.

Comment: In fact, I used UPDATE in tag of hbm2ddl.auto to avoid drop existing data.